# SSL Certificate on a parked sub domain owend by someone else?

Tags: ssl, cross-domain, cpanel, whm

Maybe it is just impossible but I have the following question :

I own an domain for example : mydomain.com . On that domain I take a wildcard SSL. So far no problem. And that domain is running on a server with online software on a sub domain for example soft.mydomain.com.

Now I have customers for that software, and I want to customize the software to their subdomains for example soft.customer1.com and soft.customer2.com.

I can do this by letting them make a DNS A record pointing to my servers IP and I park then the domains onto my subdomain soft.mydomain.com (Tested that and it works).

The question is now : Can I also take a SSL certificate on soft.customer1.com and soft.customer2.com. So that at least I also have a secure connection when for example  soft.customer1.com/login.php is used.

If possible who has to request the actual SSL certificate in that case.

Also I have full access to WHM and cpanel, running a VPS.

I understand that I could use customer1.mydomain.com/login.php , but I wonder if it just would be possible to do what I suggest.

And also it recommended to work in this way ?

Thanks upfront.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: "Can I also take a SSL certificate on soft.customer1.com and soft.customer2.com". Afaik, No that is not possible to have 1 certificate run for different domains, for different subdomains it would be fine as you already mentioned

Comment: Yes there are certificates that can handle multiple domains per cert, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Different domains can exist on a single SAN/UC certificate. Take a look at http://www.ssl.com/certificates/ucc to learn more about this certificate type.

It sounds like you have all the pieces except for this particular certificate. I hope it helps.